# Android Studioにおいてimport文が認識されない。

Tags: java, android, android-studio

現在、Androidアプリの開発中なのですが、
ライブラリクラス上でimportされているにも関わらず、import文が反映されず以下のように赤字となっている状態です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

その結果,gradleでsyncはされるものの、アプリをRunしようとするとエラーとなってしまう状態です。
何が原因となっているかお分かりの方、ご教授願えますでしょうか。

※以下のように、importは指定のフォルダにされてある状態（中身もpublicになっていて外部からアクセスできる状態。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

※以下の対処法も試しましたが効果はない状態

・file->Invalidate Caches/Restart

・Projectの,ideaフォルダ下のLibraryフォルダを削除→invalidate Cache/Restart

・Close Project -> Open an existing android studio project

※バージョン情報

Android Studio:3.5.1
Gradle:5.4.1
Gradle Plugin:3.5.1

※build.gradle(app下)(念の為載せています)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/217137

Answer (score 1):

アノテーションについては別でimplementしなきゃいけないみたいですね．
dependenciesに

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```

を追加すれば問題ないかと思います．

最新バージョンとかは調べてないので一応公式のリンクも乗っけておきます．
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html?hl=ja

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
上記、試してみようと思います。